# Converting C code to Java Code:sscanf

Tags: java, c

The C code i need to convert into Java is:

```
typedef struct
{
    short ih;
    ....
} lsettings;

int ldc_read_parameters(char *param_fnm, lsettings settings, short *image_height)
{
   FILE *fp_param;
   char line[256];
   fp_param = fopen(param_fnm, "r");

   if (fp_param) 
   {
      do fgets(line, 256, fp_param); 
         while (line[0] == '#');

      sscanf(line, "%hd", &settings.ih);
      *image_height = settings.ih;
   }
}
```

The Java code i have written is:

```
class lsettings
{
  public short ih;
  .....
}

int ldc_read_parameters(String param_fnm, lsettings settings, short image_height[])
{
    Scanner fp_param;        
    String line;
    fp_param = new Scanner(new BufferedReader(new FileReader(param_fnm)));
    if (fp_param.hasNext())
    {

        do
        {
            line=fp_param.nextLine();

        } while (line.charAt(0) == '#');
        Scanner s=new Scanner(line);
        settings.ih=s.nextShort();
        image_height[0] = settings.ih;
     }
}
```

Have i done the conversion correctly or something is wrong here. I am not sure about the sscanf function. Please help. Thanks.

Comment: What about just trying it out?

Comment: What error do you see when you try it?  Have you tried stepping through the code in a debugger?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

man sscanf

`The  scanf()  function  reads  input  from  the  standard input stream stdin, fscanf() reads input from the stream pointer stream, and
       sscanf() reads its input from the character string pointed to by str.`

`h      Indicates that the conversion will be one of d, i, o, u, x, X, or n and the next pointer  is  a  pointer  to  a  short  int  or
              unsigned short int (rather than int).`

[http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextShort()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextShort%28%29)

Both sscanf and nextShort converts next value to short (in c version you have unsigned short). If you want to have the same precision - change short to int. short in java in always signed.

Comment: IMHO `%hd` refers to short int which is signed. Or have i missed something?

Comment: `or unsigned short int` - it depends of you if input `sscanf(line, "%hd", &variable);` variable can be signed or unsigned short. In java short is always signed (char is unsigned, but I do not know how Scanner interpret it)

Comment: But in `struct lsettings` it has been defined as `short`

Comment: OK to the code is the same it this case. I check in internet and short has always 2 bytes (the same like in java). So your code should work.

Comment: Can yoy please tell me about `line` that whether it should be `fp_param.next()` or `fp_param.nextLine()`

Comment: next will return next token, so can return element from the same line `# aaa` will return aaa. nextLine return text to end of line.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/9136/discussion-between-rog-matthews-and-ajozwik)